# Powershell, getting user input for computer name and displaying that computers BIOS info, OS info and disk info

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get user input for a target computer that I can run this script for. If no computer name is specified I want to display an error message. ex. I pick dc1 and all the BIOS info, Os info and hard disk shows up for dc1 and not my local computer. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

```
#Clears the screen
cls

#Sets status to 0 just incase its not already zero, option 4 sets status to 4 and exit the loop
$status = 0

#Gets the BIOS information
$biosInfo = get-CIMInstance -Class CIM_BIOSElement |select-Object SMBIOSBIOSVersion, Manufacturer, SerialNumber, Version | Format-Table

#Gets the Operating System information
$osInfo = get-CIMInstance -Class CIM_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Caption, Version |Format-List

#Gets the Disk information
$discInfo= get-CIMInstance -Class CIM_LogicalDisk |Select-Object DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size |Format-List @{Name=‘DeviceID‘;Expression={$_.DeviceID}}, @{Name=‘FreeSpace(InPercent)’;Expression={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size,2)*100}}, @{Name=‘Size(GB)’;Expression={[int]($_.Size / 1GB)}}                                             

#Function to select computer name
function name { 

$a = get-cimInstance -Class CIM_ComputerSystem.computername

}


#Menu selection zone!
Write-Host "Query Computer System Main Menu"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "1 Display Current BIOS information"
Write-Host "2 Display Operating System Information"
Write-host "3 Display Hard Disk Information"
Write-Host "4 Exit"
Write-Host ""

do 
{

$status = read-host "Please enter and Option"
$computer = Read-Host "Enter target computer name"  

if ($computer -ne $computer){Write-host "ERROR! Please enter a target computer name" }
if ($status -ne 4){
}

#Where the menu magic happens
switch ($status){
    1{ $biosInfo ; pause}
    2{ $osInfo ; pause}
    3{ $discInfo ; pause}
    4{ $status_text = '4 Exit' ;$status = 4}
   default {"Please select a number in the list!"}
}
}
#Exits the do loop when status is equal to 4
while ($status -ne 4)
```

Comment: I figured out the error part but I still need to figure out how to select a computer that's in my domain.

Comment: What do you mean select a computer that is in your domain? As in check against AD if it is valid?

Comment: If I type in dc1 I want to show the stats for dc1 and yea I want to check against AD to see if it is valid. If that make scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to abstract your `Get-CimInstance` calls away in a function or a parameterized scriptblock.

Instead of this, which immediately executes against your local machine:

```
$OSInfo = Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_OperatingSystem
```

You want something like this:

```
$OSInfoGetter = {
    param([string]$ComputerName)

    Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName
}
```

Now you can re-invoke your scriptblock with the call operator (`&`) and supply any computername as the argument:

```
$OSInfo = &$OSInfoGetter $env:ComputerName
```

For checking the computer name that the user inputs, I'd put another `do{}while()` loop inside the first one:

```
do 
{
    $status = Read-Host "Please enter and Option"

    do{
        $Computer = Read-Host "Enter target computer name"
        if (($InvalidName = [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Computer))){
            Write-Warning "ERROR! Please enter a target computer name"
        }
    } until (-not $InvalidName)

    # switch goes here

} while ($status -ne 4)
```

You can substitute whatever logic you want in there, such as checking for existence of the machine in Active Directory